# X takes a long time to load under Lion

Tags: macos, x11

I recently upgraded to Lion.  X now takes a couple of minutes to load.  Anybody know what to change to make this go faster?

Answer (score -1):

As per the Lion technical specifications, there must be at least 2GB of RAM. Do u have ?
If yes, then there may be some other unnecessary applications using the resources of OS. These must be either stopped or removed from your Mac.

To keep your Mac clean and remove unnecessary data, you can use Stellar Speed Up Mac software.

Please make sure you have enough free space in your disk.

Comment: How does this relate to the specific X11 problem?